# Postgresql : get rows whose column name like

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not an expert in sql and Postgresql. I need to get all rows from a table where the column name contains string. To get the list of good columns, I used

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
AND table_name = 'mytable' AND column_name like 'AB%'
```

or more technically here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/246996.

But when I want to get data with the following query, I have the error: `ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT 
      column_name 
   FROM 
      information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'myschema' AND 
      table_name = 'mytable' AND column_name LIKE 'AB%'
   ) AS AB 
 FROM 
     myschema.mytable
```

Where is my error?
Thanks

Comment: You mentionend `progresql`in your question. Why did you not add this tag? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Did you mean postgresql ?

Comment: yes, sorry, so I changed the title

Comment: `AB%` in your subquery could point to multiple fields in your table. You can either be specific with the field name or use dynamic SQL to handle the case of multiple fields.

Comment: This is not how SQL works. With a database query you define a result table. This means you must declare which columns to select. You cannot have a query that finds out which columns to select at runtime. You can of course run one query to get the column names, then write a query based on those column names, then run that new query. This is called dynamic SQL. In PostgreSQL you'd typically use the programming language PL/pgSQL that is built into the DBMS for this, so all this takes place in the tdatabase server. But you could just as well write an app in Java, C#, whatever.

Comment: Not clear to me whether you: 1) Want to find all columns in table that have name starting with `AB` or 2) Or get all rows that have values  starting with `AB` in some set of columns. If 1) Then your `SELECT  column_name  FROM  ... ` would work on its own. If 2) Then you will need to add to your question more information: a) Sample table values. b) Expected output.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I want all rows only for column whose name begin by "AB"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a function using dynamic queries, like this:

```
create or replace function myfunction()
returns setof varchar as 
$$
declare
  l_column varchar;
begin   
    --get the column name
    select column_name into l_column 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_schema = 'myschema'
    and table_name = 'mytable' and column_name like 'AB%';
   -- dynamic query passing column name
   return query execute format('select %I '
   'from myschema.mytable', l_column);   
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

then

```
select myfunction();
```

this is an example for one returning column, for more info check [the official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: Thanks @Pepe, probably a good solution, but I got the "permission denied for schema public" error. That is because I'm working with Palantir Slate query, which is a bit different than a real db